# Why does Fairbanks, AK have a terminal area chart?

Tags: aviation-history, faa, aeronautical-charts

It's a relatively uncluttered airspace. Why have a TAC?

#### [FAI Terminal Area Chart](https://skyvector.com/?ll=64.72008642109647,-148.1122722325821&chart=130&zoom=5)

[image: Fairbanks, AK Terminal Area Chart depicting the Fairbanks TRSA and surrounding area]

Arguably, Louisville, KY has at least the same complexity, and since it's UPS's hub it's far more active. Plus, it's a legit controlled airspace, instead of a terminal radar area.

#### SDF as shown on [the St. Louis sectional](https://skyvector.com/?ll=38.175220423237775,-85.69136447923044&chart=21&zoom=3)

[image: Portion of the St. Louis VFR sectional depicting the Louisville, KY Class C airspace and surrounding area]

Are there historical reasons, reasons which aren't immediately obvious, or is it just some kind of cynical inflation of importance?

Comment: Fairbanks is just as much "legit controlled airspace" as Louisville is. Class E, *by definition*, is controlled airspace.

Comment: Also note that the ICAO code for Fairbanks is **not** KFAI... which is yet another example of why pilots operating in the US should be in the habit of giving the three- or four-character FAA Location ID and **NOT** the four-letter ICAO code.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but two differences are that PAFA has significant terrain close to the airport, and there's also a lot of military activity around it (at least, that's what some of the comments on the TAC imply). Neither of those things are an issue for KSDF. I used to fly out of KLOU, and I don't think anyone considers it "complex" airspace. The PAFA area looks a lot more complex to me, in fact.

Comment: @Pondlife I agree; KSDF is a pretty simple class C that I wouldn’t think twice about flying through. PAFA is part of a triple-primary TRSA with six non-towered airports in their surface areas, plus significant terrain and nearby SUA; I would appreciate the added detail of a TAC if I had to fly there VFR.

Comment: Aside from the nearby military fields, PAFA has commercial aviation and a huge amount of GA traffic.  In addition to the 'main' runway, there is a shorter paved runway as well as a gravel ski strip and a water runway.  I count 6 visual reference points around the area. Much more variability than that organized stream of UPS traffic at SDF.

Comment: @randomhead thanks for the edits, they make the question better. Definitely didn't know that about the ICAO code. We'll agree to disagree that Class E is a controlled airspace in the sense of VFR pilots having to establish comms with ATC. There's plenty of Class E in the US, but FAI is the only one I know of which gets a TAC.

Comment: @KennSebesta It looks like the chart shows that FAI is class D, meaning that a VFR pilot would indeed need to establish comms before entering. I’m not sure if that’s what you meant, though.

Comment: @KennSebesta TRSA is a special kind of class E. And “controlled” means something very different to VFR and IFR pilots.

Comment: @StephenS as an instrument pilot, I agree completely. But a TAC isn't particularly helpful for me when flying instrument, it's primarily a tool I use for VFR flight. I'm not saying FAI's TRSA shouldn't have a TAC, but it's the outlier in that there are no other TRSA which warrant a TAC, and the only two Class C in the nation which have a TAC are in Alaska and *all* of Puerto Rico.

Comment: @Pondlife, whelp, maybe that right there is why there's a TAC. I had missed the Class D hidden in the contours of the TSRA and Class E. It's a lot easier to see on the TAC than the sectional!

Comment: @KennSebesta AFAIK, every TRSA has at least one class D, and most don’t get a TAC. PAFA is weird because it has 3 D’s. That’s probably part of why it does.